# Writing output files with SAXON / XQuery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, saxon

I'd like to save some xml fragments from one big XML into individual files. The source XML looks like this:

```
<files>
  <file name="foo.xml">
    <data>...</data>
    Something
  </file>
  ...
  <file name="bar.xml">
    Something else
  </file>
</files>
```

As far as I know there is no standard result-document function in XQuery (just saxon/user extensions). But we have `fn:transform`, which can execute XSLT which has `<xsl:result-document>`, so I wrote the following code:

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";

declare option saxon:output "method=xml";
declare option saxon:output "indent=yes";

declare variable $nl := "&#10;";
declare variable $input as item() external;

declare function local:saveFile($path, $content)
{
  let $stylesheet := document{ 
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="file:///F:/z.txt" method="xml">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <success>Created file: {$path}</success>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 
   }
   let $transFormResultMap := fn:transform(
      map{
        "stylesheet-node": $stylesheet
        ,"source-node": document { $content }
      }
   )
   return $transFormResultMap ? output
};


for $file in $input/files/file
let $fileName := fn:string(( $file/@name, $file/@NAME )[1])
let $content := $file/*
return 
  local:saveFile($fileName, $content)
```

The problem is, that no file are written actually (and no error message). To simplify it I use the absolute path "F:\z.txt" in the script (it should use $path). Any idea what is wrong? If I do the same without XQuery (pure XSLT) it seems to work.

(I use "Saxon-HE 9.9.1.7J")

Comment: The `fn:transform` function returns a map with the result documents, it doesn't write them to the URI. So `$transFormResultMap('file:///F:/z.txt')` will contain the result. Writing it to the file system is something you would need to do from XQuery with `fn:put` or the EXPath file module, I think all of that is only available in the commercial editions. Of course, if you run XQuery from a host language like Java or C#, you can also use Saxon's serializer to write an XDM value to a file.

Comment: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/put.html says "Available in all Saxon editions." but I don't think that is correct.

Comment: You can actually provide a `post-process` function as an option to the `fn:transform` function that is called for each result document but the spec says "this post-processing function might be used to save a copy of the result document to persistent storage. For example, if the implementation provides access to the EXPath File library [EXPath], then a serialized document might be written to filestore by calling the file:write function". The default for this function does nothing but return the result.

Comment: It says that is available in XQuery Update 1.0, but here http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xquery/update you can find the following sentence:
Update is available only in Saxon-EE, and is supported only if explicitly requested.

Comment: eXist or baseX might be useful here, as you can add the "fragments" to, I believe a "database".  Being just a collection of documents, or so I understand.

Comment: It seems as if this should work based on the example here https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/saxon/transform.html combined with the fact that fn:transform is now supported in HE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be not really possible without extension-functions, therefore I just switched to the pure XSLT-solution (but I prefer XQuery):

This is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:param name="dir"></xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:template match="/files/file">
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="./@name" />
    <xsl:result-document href="{$dir}{$filename}" method="xml">
      <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
    <success>Created file: <xsl:value-of select="$filename" /></success>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```